# Flash actionscript - gotoAndPlay() error 1009 cannot access a property or method of a null object

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm a newbie and need some help.

I'm making a game in Flash and I keep getting an Error 1009.

I have my gameover conditions listed, and every time a gameover occurs and the gotoAndPlay(1) code is called, I get the error. The error disappears if I comment out the gotoAndPlay(1) line.

Here is the code:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameOver);
    function gameOver(e:Event):void{
        //gameover conditions
        if (ball.y > 799 - ball.width / 2 && score > 0)
        {
            trace("GameOver!");
            if (this.contains(ball)){
            this.removeChild(ball);
            trace("Chicken removed");
            }
gotoAndPlay(1);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you need to determine what line the error occurs on. which IDE are you using? 1009 means that you tried to access a property of something that is null - such as "ball.y" when ball is null.

Comment: I'm currently using Flash Professional as my IDE by writing the code directly onto each frame it pertains to.

Comment: try running in debug mode - it should stop on the line where the error occurs

Comment: the debug mode definitely helped! i realized some of my background symbols I had moving were not removed before switching frames. that must have caused the error. Thanks so much! sorry for the newbie question

Comment: no problem - we all have to start somewhere ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed your code:

```
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameOver);
    function gameOver(e:Event):void{
        //gameover conditions
        if (ball.y > 799 - ball.width / 2 && score > 0)
        {
            trace("GameOver!");
            if (this.contains(ball)){
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameOver);
            this.removeChild(ball);
            trace("Chicken removed");
            }
gotoAndPlay(1);
}
}
```

Added removeEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

this could be caused because inline functions runs in it's own (global) scope. It can still access variables defined in the function though, so commonly this is solved like this.

```
  this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameOver);
  var obj:DisplayObject = this;

  function gameOver(e:Event):void {
      //gameover conditions
      if (ball.y > 799 - ball.width / 2 && score > 0) {
          trace("GameOver!");
          if (this.contains(ball)) {
              this.removeChild(ball);
              trace("Chicken removed");
          }
          obj.gotoAndPlay(1);
      }
  }
```